# How to detect when an exception is in flight?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++

In C++ (MSVC) how can I test whether an exception is currently "in flight".  Ie, code which is being called as part of a class destructor may be getting invoked because an exception is unwinding the stack..  How can I detect this case as opposed to the normal case of a destructor being called due to a normal return?

Comment: I feel I ought to defend my reason for wanting to do this.  I want to write out some debugging state when my piece of code falls over.  To do this I want to put some logging code into the destructor which will write out some internal state.  I don't want this on every destructor call as in my test setup it runs normally for several iterations before failing.  So..  In my destructor I am now using "if (uncaught_exception()) {..}" to enable some extra logging.  The debugger isn't enough for me, as I need to do a fair amount of expensive conversion to make the internal state human readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it's possible to do this, call uncaught_exception() in <exception> header.
One reason you might want to do this is before throwing an exception in a destructor, which would lead to program termination if this destructor was called as part of stack unwinding.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1atwat8%28VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: This works perfectly, I must have been Googling with the wrong keywords not to spot this. :)

Comment: Note that while this tells you whether an exception is in flight, knowledge of that fact is almost never useful. In particular, when used in a destructor it does not tell you whether you can/should throw an exception on failure: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm

Comment: Destructors should simply never ever throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 9):

Before you go too far down the uncaught_exception() path, look at http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm

Answer (score 3):

In C++17, `std::uncaught_exceptions` (note the plural "s") was introduced. This allows you to capture the "nested unwinding" count in the ctor and compare the captured value to the current value when the dtor is executed. That way you can know if your object is being destroyed because its scope was left by means of an exception (dtor current value > captured value).

Which means you can finally implement stuff like "auto-undo" guards in C++, yay. :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for

```
// Returns true only if a thrown exception is being currently processed
namespace std {
    bool uncaught_exception();
};
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1atwat8.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there's a better way but could you not catch and rethrow the exception?

Answer (score -1):

one way would to replace the exception handling machinery with your [own](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/exceptionhandler.aspx?display=Print).

on the other hand, it always begs for the question - why would one want to do that?..

a few more links on the subj: [Reversing Microsoft Visual C++ Part I: Exception Handling](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21) and [The exception model](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/10/01/51524.aspx)